# serializing union type via custom function: "static assertion failed:: typex::value"

Tags: opencl, boost-serialization

I am serializing the `cl_long2` type from OpenCL which is defined like this (simplified from `/usr/include/CL/cl_platform.hpp`):

```
typedef int64_t cl_long;
typedef union
{
    cl_long __attribute__ ((aligned(16))) s[2];
    struct{ cl_long  x, y; };
    struct{ cl_long  s0, s1; };
    struct{ cl_long  lo, hi; };
} cl_long2;
```

I defined the following stand-alone serialization function:

```
namespace boost{ namespace serialization {
template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, cl_long2 &i, const unsigned version){
   ar & make_nvp("x",i.x);
   ar & make_nvp("y",i.y);
}

}};
```

When I compile my code, which invokes a serialization of cl_long2 from as a class member, I am getting the following error, which I cannot understand (the error is the same if it is not a `std::vector<cl_long2>`, just a stand-alone variable):

```
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/check.hpp: In function ‘void boost::archive::detail::check_object_level() [with T = cl_long2]’:
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:438:9:   instantiated from ‘static void boost::archive::detail::load_non_pointer_type<Archive>::invoke(Archive&, T&) [with T = cl_long2, Archive = boost::archive::xml_iarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:592:5:   instantiated from ‘void boost::archive::load(Archive&, T&) [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_iarchive, T = cl_long2]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:66:9:   instantiated from ‘void boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<Archive>::load_override(T&, int) [with T = cl_long2, Archive = boost::archive::xml_iarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/basic_xml_iarchive.hpp:86:9:   instantiated from ‘void boost::archive::basic_xml_iarchive<Archive>::load_override(const boost::serialization::nvp<T>&, int) [with T = cl_long2, Archive = boost::archive::xml_iarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp:93:9:   instantiated from ‘void boost::archive::xml_iarchive_impl<Archive>::load_override(T&, int) [with T = const boost::serialization::nvp<cl_long2>, Archive = boost::archive::xml_iarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:60:9:   [ skipping 5 instantiation contexts ]
/usr/include/boost/serialization/split_free.hpp:58:9:   instantiated from ‘static void boost::serialization::free_loader<Archive, T>::invoke(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_iarchive, T = std::vector<cl_long2>]’
/usr/include/boost/serialization/split_free.hpp:74:5:   instantiated from ‘void boost::serialization::split_free(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_iarchive, T = std::vector<cl_long2>]’
/usr/include/boost/serialization/vector.hpp:151:5:   instantiated from ‘void boost::serialization::serialize(Archive&, std::vector<U, Allocator>&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_iarchive, U = cl_long2, Allocator = std::allocator<cl_long2>]’
/usr/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:128:9:   instantiated from ‘void boost::serialization::serialize_adl(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_iarchive, T = std::vector<cl_long2>]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:188:5:   instantiated from ‘void boost::archive::detail::iserializer<Archive, T>::load_object_data(boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive&, void*, unsigned int) const [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_iarchive, T = std::vector<cl_long2>]’
myFile.cpp:368:2:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/check.hpp:60:5: error: static assertion failed: "typex::value"
```

The same error appears regardless of whether the archive type is xml or binary. I am using boost::serialization 1.46.

Any hints?

**EDIT: A smaller example including error is at http://ideone.com/4UgCn

Comment: by any chance, is "BOOST_NO_INTRINSIC_INT64_T" defined?

Comment: No, it is not (I grepped through boost headers, and it does not exist either). `int64_t` is a system-defined type (Linux with gcc toolchain).

Comment: Well looking at the asserting line, it says "trap attempts to serialize objects marked not_serializable". You should look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html especially at the "not_serializable" property which is set for your datatype for some reason or another.

Comment: I added the http://ideone.com/4UgCn with a minimal example (the struct o serialize is yet smaller, just a union). I thought boost::serialization handles unions just fine, as long as serialization function is provided.

Comment: @Pompei2: very good, adding `BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(long2,boost::serialization::object_serializable)` solves the problem. Thanks! Can you post it as answers othat I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the line where the assertion fails ([detail/check.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/boost/archive/detail/check.hpp):60), there is a comment right above it:

```
// trap attempts to serialize objects marked
// not_serializable
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(typex::value);
```

The [documentation of this 'not_serializable' trait](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html) says that you have to enable this `long2` type first. As you found out, this is done by:

```
BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(long2,boost::serialization::object_serializable)
```